# Port forwading with vpn trought http proxy

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, http-proxy

My connection is nat, I can not do port forwading normally, just that I need this functionality, so I bought a vps and I hosted a vpn with openvpn, everything went well and I always used this system to be able to make port forwading . Shortly I will need to use a proxy http to connect to this vpn, I'm going to set it directly from the config I use to connect, I wondered if I could still port forwading through the vpn even if I'm connected with a proxy. Sorry for English, but I use the translator.

Comment: Why do you need to use a proxy? If you're using a proxy you're usually bound to use the ports it using. SOCKS proxies might have some more options. Tunneling a VPN through a proxy might be difficult.

Comment: @Seth The circuit will be proxy> vpn not vpn> proxy, I am forced to use a proxy http because without using the internet it does not work.

Comment: Yes, hence I said it will probably be difficult. It depends on what kind of proxy it is and what ports are available. You might be able to change your VPN configuration to support ports that your proxy.

Comment: @Seth I thought about it and if the vpn I use for now successfully succeeds in bypassing the nat and acting as a server for nat hole punching, why it has problems if I connect to the vpn with a proxy? It would be like a "layer of nat more"

Comment: Because a proxy can do all kinds of things. It might add headers that confuse your VPN, it might modify the packet in some way, it might discard packets because they don't look like regular HTTP requests.

Comment: @Seth It's a normal proxy that I create with squid, without changing any settings